# How do I use taylor formula for complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

There is a reference that says that by "taylor's forumla,"

$f(w)=f(z)+\frac{df}{dw}(w-z)-\frac{df}{d\overline{w}}\overline{w-z}+o(|w-z|)$

Could someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: This is a two dimensional linear approximation, which is a minimal form of 2d Taylor's formula. A slight oddity is that the two derivatives $d/dw$ and $d/d\overline{w}$ might be a bit unfamiliar, but they're relatively common in some complex analysis applications.

Comment: @ davidlowryduda♦ can you direct me toward some reference that I can look for? What is a minimal form and linear approximation?

Comment: How are we able to treat both $w$ and $bar{w}$ as two different varaibles?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}^1$, a linear approximation of a function $f(x)$ is $f(x) = f(x_0) + C (x - x_0) + error$ for some constant $C$. The best linear approximation is $C = f'(x_0)$, in which case the error is $o(\lvert x - x_0 \rvert)$ as $x \to x_0$ (Indeed, this is one way to define differentiability). By "minimal form", I meant that this is a "trivial application of Taylor's Theorem"; I say trivial only because this is actually the definition of a derivative, much weaker than Taylor's Theorem. Finally, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_one_complex_variable

Comment: The link directs me toward the definition of $d/dz$ and $d/d\overline{z}$. I wish I could understand. Do you think $\frac{df}{d\bar{w}}\overline{w-z}$ is a typo and should be omitted?